# Sub-class a vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have some repeating functionality that many components will use. So my first thought is I should create a base component and have my components inherit/subclass from this.

But maybe this is not possible in vue.js and maybe its not the vue.js way to do things? If I explain my use-case can you suggest how best I implement this in vue.js?

BasePage.vue

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'animated-page',

  watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
      // conditionally choose animations depending on route
      const toDepth = to.path.split('/').length
      const fromDepth = from.path.split('/').length
      this.transitionName = toDepth < fromDepth ? 'slide-right' : 'slide-left'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
... my animations
</style>
```

About.vue

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  // somehow inherit from BasePage
  name: 'about-page',

  ... 'about' specific code
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`extend`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend) to subclass the Vue constructor, and you can use it on components to subclass them.

In general, though, you should prefer composition to inheritance and use [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#ad) where you can.

> Mixins are a flexible way to distribute reusable functionalities for Vue components. A mixin object can contain any component options. When a component uses a mixin, all options in the mixin will be “mixed” into the component’s own options.